# Verb tense compatibility

Tags: tenses

My teacher gave me a question

**When I (come)______, she (leave)______ for Cali ten minutes ago.**

and my job is to complete this sentence with any verb tense provided it makes sense.

My teacher said it must be only one sentence:

**When I came, she had left for Cali ten minutes ago.**

But I think there are some sentences that make sense:
**(1)** When I **came**, she **left** for Cali ten minutes ago. (it means that I came as soon as she left, so we met each other for a very short time, so I could give her the present.

**(2)** When I **came**, she **had left** for Cali ten minutes ago. (It means she left for Cali before I came, so I couldn't met her and give her the present)

**(3)** When I **had came**, she **left** for Cali ten minutes ago. (It means I came before she left some minutes, so we met each other for some minutes, so I could give her the present and talk to her about something.

**(4)** When I **came**, she **was leaving** for Cali ten minutes ago.

Do you think **(1), (2), (3) and (4)** are correct? If not, please help me fix it.

Comment: *None* of those sentences, including the one by your teacher, are very good. Your teacher's version should be 'When I came (better: *arrived* or *got there*), she had already left for Cali ten minutes earlier'. Even better is replacing *when* with *By the time*.

Comment: Apart from the fact the sentence is not great anyway, some other points: _when I had came_ is not grammatical (_When I had come_ could be grammatical) and _she was leaving ten minutes ago_ makes no sense in this context.

Answer (score 1):

> When I (come)______, she (leave)______ for Cali ten minutes ago.

I think a better sentence would be:

> By the time I got there, she had already left for Cali ten minutes before.

But if you have to fill in the blanks, the best I could suggest would be:

> When I arrived, she had left for Cali ten minutes ago.

Even that is bad. The word "ago" shouldn't be present, since "ago" refers to a time before "now", not a time before another time.

If you change "ago" to "before", you can get close:

> When I arrived, she had left for Cali ten minutes before.

And, btw, no one from California actually calls it Cali.

Comment: Who said Cali refers to California? There's more to the world than the U S of A...

Answer (score -1):

If you eliminate 'ten minutes ago', the following sentences would be correct:

1. When I came, she was leaving for Cali (I arrived right when she was leaving so we met for a short time)
2. When I came, she had left for Cali (I arrived after she had left, so I didn't meet her)
3. When I came, she left for Cali (she left after I arrived, so we probably had enough time to have a long conversation. It's not specified when exactly she leaves after my arrival)

But since the sentence specifically states the time of her leaving as 'ten minutes ago', the last sentence is incorrect here. But both 1 and 2 are still correct.